# CSS border is not showing in <p> tag?

Tags: html, css

I am currently very new to css and html5.

I don't know what I have done wrong in the code please tell me my mistake.

Why Border in not showing in p tag?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Margin</title>
    <style>
        h1{
            border:10px solid red;
            margin:25px 50px 75px 100px;
        }
        h3{
            border:1px solid red;
            margin:auto;
        }
        div{
            margin:10px 100px 1cm 200pt;
        }
        h2.mf{
            margin-bottom:inherit;
        }
        p.mf{/*Not Working*/
            margin:inherit;
            border: 5px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is head 1.</h1>
    <h3>This is head 3.</h3>
    
    <div class= "mf">
        <h2>This is again h2</h2>
        <p>This is para....</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If h2 working in "mf" div?

Comment: use `.mf > p` and `.mf > h2`

Comment: and learn complete about `css selectors`  -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector `p.mf` mean that p tag has class `mf`.

You need change to `.mf p`  because your p tag inside div class `mf`

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Margin</title>
    <style>
        h1 {
            border:10px solid red;
            margin:25px 50px 75px 100px;
        }
        h3 {
            border:1px solid red;
            margin:auto;
        }
        div {
            margin:10px 100px 1cm 200pt;
        }
        h2.mf {
            margin-bottom: inherit;
            color: green;
        }
        .mf p {/*Not Working*/
            margin:inherit;
            border: 5px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is head 1.</h1>
    <h3>This is head 3.</h3>
    
    <div class= "mf">
        <h2>This is again h2</h2>
        <p>This is para....</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is special in h2? Why h2.mf works?

Comment: h2.mf can not work, I add color: green but it can not show green, if change to .mf h2 it will work.

Answer (score 3):

There is no `p` HTML Element with class `mf`

> I'd select this style if I were to style all `p` in HTML document

```
p {
  margin: inherit;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

or

> I'd select below style if I were to style all `p` elements who is child of element with `.mf`

```
.mf p {
  margin: inherit;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```css
h1 {
  border: 10px solid red;
  margin: 25px 50px 75px 100px;
}

h3 {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: auto;
}

div {
  margin: 10px 100px 1cm 200pt;
}

h2.mf {
  margin-bottom: inherit;
}

p {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<h3>This is head 3.</h3>

<div class="mf">
  <h2>This is again h2</h2>
  <p>This is para....</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @AbhayKumar when you write `h2.mf` you are asking to apply the style of all `h2` that has `mf` class. But you don't have a `h2` element with `mf` class. So it doesn't apply. Also when you say `h2` you are selecting all `h2` elements that has class `mf` or not. Doesn't matter but it sholuld be a `h2` element. Hope you understand

Answer (score 1):

it's because you haven't initialized the class in your `<p>` tag :D .

like this :

```
        <p class="mf">This is para....</p>
```

or you can try this in your css

```
        p{
            margin:inherit;
            border: 5px solid red;
        }
```

note : dot (.) in css is to initialize class

Answer (score 1):

You use `.mf` because of your div class being `mf` and then you would put `p` afterwards to specify for the `<p>` tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Margin</title>
    <style>
        h1{
            border:10px solid red;
            margin:25px 50px 75px 100px;
        }
        h3{
            border:1px solid red;
            margin:auto;
        }
        div{
            margin:10px 100px 1cm 200pt;
        }
        h.mf{
            margin-bottom:inherit;
        }
        .mf p {/*Not Working*/
            margin:inherit;
            border: 5px solid red;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is head 1.</h1>
    <h3>This is head 3.</h3>
    
    <div class= "mf">
        <h2>This is again h2</h2>
        <p>This is para....</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).